# How to filter samples in a DGEList in edgeR

Tags: rna-seq

I am trying to filter samples in a DGEList object created in edgeR by an attribute I have called "architecture".

$samples looks like:

```
$samples
              group lib.size norm.factors architecture
15-AM_p_ap        1 36252192            1            p
15-LM-11_p_mi     1 34394164            1            p
15-LM-14_p_mi     1 37147178            1            p
15-LM-19_p_up     1 39236017            1            p
15-LM-2_p_lo      1 36543297            1            p
68 more rows ...
```

I want to subset the list to exclude the samples with the architecture designation of "w".  I have tried more things than I can remember, the latest being:

```
y.subset <- y[which(!y$samples$architecture == "w"),]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of your comma so that the condition is applied to the columns of the data frame like so:

```
y.subset <- y[,which(!y$samples$architecture == "w")]
```

As the goal here is to filter on the columns of the y$counts object, which are reflected as rows of y$samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the expression further "which" is not strictly necessary.

y.subset <- y[,!y$samples$architecture == "w"]